# Why doesn't KE of annihilation electrons necessarily have to be equal to each other?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, radiation

We know that when a high energy gamma ray(E >= 1022 keV because the total energy of 1 electron at rest and 1 positron at rest is 511 keV) passes near a high Z(atomic weight) atomic nucleus interacts with the electrical field of the nucleus and there is a probability that this high energetic gamma-ray will create positron and electron pairs in order to conserve the linear momentum.

However, when the total energy of the incoming gamma ray is bigger than 1022 keV, this pair is created their total energy is not necessarily shared equally, there can be a difference in the KE shared by the electron-positron pair. For example, if the total energy of the incoming gamma ray is 1044 keV the pair of positron and electron does not have to be 522 keV each; one can be 523 keV while the other can have 521 keV. Why is that?

What does determine which particle will have which value for total energy for pair of electron and positron?

(Any remaining energy of more than 1022 keV will be given to each particle of pair as KE.)

My source(free): https://www.nrc.gov/docs/ML1122/ML11229A667.pdf (62th page of 110)

Comment: Your link describes the pair production in the laboratory system. One has to use a Lorentz transformation and go to the center of mass system where the behavior of pair production  has the symmetry you expect. see this analysis on L transformations, https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Nuclear_and_Particle_Physics/Book%3A_Nuclear_and_Particle_Physics_(Walet)/09%3A_Relativistic_Kinematics/9.03%3A_Transformations_between_CM_and_lab_frame  .

Comment: Going to the lab from the CM creates the difference observed, depending on the angles the pair and the field have  to the photon direction. I am too old to trust my memory to write an answer. Lets hope somebody answers it well.

Comment: @annav:  That argument about the CM frame works for a two-to-two process, since the product particles must have the same magnitude of their momenta and therefore the same energies.  But here we're talking about a two-to-three process ($X+\gamma  \to X + e + e$), and so it's not obvious to me that the electron & positron energies must equal, even in the CM frame.

Comment: No matter how manny particles there will be a distribution in the CM that can be predicted. according to the probability of the scattering depending on the strength of the field . I think that the pair will be almost of  equal and opposite momentum  in the cm but its a guess. in the lab they will becone unequal because of the angles and the Lorentz transformation.

Comment: @annav:  I'd buy that they're "almost equal" in the CM frame because of the large mass difference between the nucleus and the electron;  there's probably some approximation that can be made.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert  Just a thought: Is the reason for kinetic energy difference in pair particles about how the nucleus was positioned relative to the newly created electron-positron pair in the instance that pair came to be? The recoil of nucleus happens and thus a pair creation is a 2 -> 3 body process

Comment: Yes, in principle you can use conservation of energy and conservation of momentum to determine what the energies of the electrons should be, assuming that the electron goes off in direction A, the positron goes off in direction B, and the nucleus recoils in direction C.  But actually solving for these energies is tricky.  (That said, the notion of "how the nucleus was positioned relative to the $e^--e^+$ pair" is not really well-defined in quantum mechanics, and it's probably best to try to avoid thinking about the problem this way.)